# doublerender error in controller of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I do get all the time i call the controller in the browser a doublerenderError as listed below. please tell me why.. i do render just once.. and i never have a redirect or something like that :/

This is my controller

```
class BezirkController < ApplicationController
caches_page :index
  def index
        Bezirk.find_each do |bezirk|
                render :json => bezirk
        end
  end
end
```

this is the error msg:

```
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:15:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
app/controllers/bezirk_controller.rb:5:in `block in index'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in find_each'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:21:in `each'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:21:in `block in find_each'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:72:in `find_in_batches'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:20:in `find_each'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/querying.rb:8:in `find_each'
app/controllers/bezirk_controller.rb:4:in `index'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__149640372__process_action__195728711__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:339:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__312425612__call__1069087096__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:207:in `validate'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:181:in `lookup'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: `def index; render :json => Bezirk.all ; end; end`

Comment: You are rendering multiple times: for each Bezirk you try to render it in JSON. Use @apneadiving solution to render once.

Comment: thx! i completly didnt see this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in an each loop, which is calling Render each pass through the loop.

either do:

```
def index
  render :json => Bezirk.all
end
```

or

```
def index
  Bezirk.find_each do |bezirk|
    ...  #build up a hash to render
  end
  render :json => your_built_hash
end
```

-------  EDITED ---

```
def index
  bezirks = []
  Bezirk.find_each do |bezirk|
    bezirks << bezirk.attributes
  end
  render :json => {:bezirks => bezirks}
end
```

Comment: Please can you tell me how i can build up this hash in the each do loop?

Or can you provide me a link where i can read about this.. i am really stuck :/